# is there a method to copy a line if a particular string is different in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Background**: After running tests, we get a file which has this string "seed" followed by a unique seed number and that is in a single line

Ex

```
testname some string some string some string -seed xxxxxxx some string some string
```

i have created a script which picks up entire line from each test and dumps them in single file failed_dump.txt

Question: if i run the script 2nd time i want to only pick up the non-existing test dump in my failed_dump.txt and update it in the same file. one method is to compare the seed number as its unique. i am unable to proceed forward with this,

I have tried this below code which is not working properly.

```
with open("failed_dump","r") as data1:
for x in new_list:
    for y in data1:
        if y.partition("seed")[2] not in x.partition("seed")[2]:
            update_list.append(y)
```

Also i have tried

```
for x in new_list:
if all(y.partition("seed")[2] not in x.partition("seed")[2] for y in data1):
    update_list.append(x)
```

but the 2nd method is returning null list. Please help.

Comment: Hi friend, please indent your snippet correctly, second - can you provide `new_list` as well?

Comment: moreover, some data is missed e.g: how does you save the data in your file? `<filename>, <seed>`? what is the exact input and output you want?, p.s - It's seems like you are iterate over results of sort of regression, which obtain random seed, but it does not mean that two different test cannot share the same seed, although it picked up randomly